# Change a specific label in enumerate environment

Tags: numbering, enumerate, languages

I'm using `arabtex`, and there is an error in the package.

When using `\alph` as a label for `enumerate`, it works correctly, however it is not in Arabic alphabetical order. As you would expect for the latin `\alph` to go `a,b,c,d...etc.`, for Arabic it would go `أ، ب، ج، د،ذ...etc`. The wrong letter is the third one, it appears as something different.

I'm aware of the fact that I can change any label manually by adding the label in square brackets after `\item`, however, that would be tedious especially if I have more than three items. If I edit the label of the third item, the wrong label will go to the fourth one and so on.

My question is, can I change the third letter throughout the whole document either by using a command or editing the `arabtex` package if that's possible.

Edit:
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\begin{document}

\setcode{utf8}
\begin{arabtex}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item  
    \item <Label of this item is wrong.>  
    \item  
    \item 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{arabtex}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of wrong behavior]

Comment: A Google search for `latex arabtex collation order` finds some hints that others have encountered a similar problem. Links there might suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

add `\usepackage{xepersian}` in your preamble and then apply the enumeration environment like this

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\item foo
.
.
\end{enumerate}
```